# Dynamic variable in multiple language with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs

I use laravel with react, so doing `{Lang.get('profile.name',{name: someVar})}`will return me some value from my English language file. But I have to mix some html tag as I want the name to be bold, thought of using dangerouslySetInnerHTML but failed with the code below

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    return {__html: Lang.get('profile.name', {name: '<strong>someVar</strong>'}})}
}} />
```

Comment: use ```{!! .. !!}``` instead of ```{{ .. }}```

Comment: I don't get it, can you please explain and post an answer?

Comment: are you sure about your code grammar? change code to ```<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    return {__html: Lang.get('profile.name', {name: '<strong>someVar</strong>'})}
}} />
``` and let me know result

Comment: @Mohammadb Tried your code, got error of Unexpected token

Comment: which version of laravel you use?

Comment: @Mohammadb does it matter? latest version